# Book recommendation for 7 year old

Tags: geology, teaching

By some poorly understood series of events, I have managed to convince my 7 year old daughter that she wants to be a geologist when she's older. Of course I'm aware that this likely won't be the case, but I thought I'd try to seize on the moment and get her a book on geology.

So I am looking for any recommendations for a children's book on geology, perhaps with facts/experiments about stuff that she can find in the garden/in her local area. We live in a reasonably urban part of the world (Surrey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 books that come to mind:

- [National Geographic Readers: Rocks and Minerals (2012)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1426310382), a richly illustrated guide for kids.
- [Ultimate Explorer Field Guide: Rocks and Minerals (2016)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1426323018) by Nancy Honovich, a guide focussed on getting kids outside, looking at rocks in their backyards and on the camping.

Considering you're in the UK, afterwards I'd start with some experiments about limestone. National Geographic used to have rock kits for kids, not sure who else sells them near you. With the keywords "rock kit kids uk" I get some results that may be worth a look at.

Answer (score 1):

What a nice question! There is not a whole lot of literature on geology aimed at children but it is a great subject to get interested in (OK, I am biased). A quick Amazon search suggests "The Street beneath our Feet" by Charlotte Guillard is very well thought of as a starter - and she is an English author. Of more grown up books which could provide inspiration for a an enthusiastic kid I would suggest The Hidden Landscape by Richard Fortey, The Geology of Britain by Peter Toghill , The illustrated Guide to Rocks and minerals by John Farndon.
Mary Anning is of course the great british pioneering female role-model and well worth using to help inspire your daughter - not least since there are two films getting close to release based on her story. She has also inspired authors so there are plenty of books to choose from at different levels. Once you have learnt a bit you are perfectly placed to follow up by visiting the NHM in London to see specimens she collected and to visit Lyme Regis to start collecting your own. If you do then make sure to visit the Philpott Museum in Lyme and to go on a guided fossil hunting walk - the best ones are organised by the museum and by Charmouth Heritage centre. On the way back go to Kimmeridge to visit the amazing new museum of Steve Etches' fossils.
There is also a lot of good geology on your doorstep - The Weald is one of the best places to explore the relationship between landscape and geology. I don't think there are any good books for children but you can get copies of the Geological Survey handbook or the New Naturalist book (ancient but a classic) to research the basics (Chalk/Downs, Gault Clay/ Vale of Holmesdale, Greensand Ridge (eg Box Hill)/Lower Greensand, Low Weald/Weald Clay (dinosaurs), High Weald / Wealden Sandstone (e.g Ashdown Forest, Wellington Rocks in Tunbridge Wells) then drive south to explore it.
Finally don't forget the Isle of Wight.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thoughtful reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'd splash out and buy 50 A4 sized books on science and nature and history: Astronomy, Stars, Human body, Insects, Rocks, Gemstones, inventions, all for 6-12 year olds, with big pretty pictures and informative texts.

Most of these books cost 1-2 dollars to buy and have plenty of reviews:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=minerals&rh=n%3A69&ref=nb_sb_noss

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=earth&rh=n%3A69&ref=nb_sb_noss

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=volcanos&rh=n%3A69&ref=nb_sb_noss

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=planet&rh=n%3A69&ref=nb_sb_noss

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=fossils&rh=n%3A69&ref=nb_sb_noss

I don't think a kids home without 100 science and learning books would be fair on the kids. I'd devote 1 meter by 1 meter at least for it. She will probably change her mind and pick some other interests as a result! Make sure you get the big books for kids, little books are fiddly and made for travel.

At my local flea market shop I think i can get 10 books for a 5er.